# virtual host using jerseyclient 1.18

Tags: jersey-client

Can anyone help me how to implement below using jerseyclient 1.18,this is most probably related to virtual host.

`curl  -k -H 'Host:b' https://a`

Generally i just know how to connect one ip using code like below

```
Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource2 = client.resource("https://a");
        ClientResponse response2 = webResource2.accept("application/json").header("user-agent", "").get(ClientResponse.class);
        if (response2.getStatus() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response2.getStatus());
        }

        String output2 = response2.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println("\n============Response============");
        System.out.println(output2);
```